# Range input and progress bar issue with increment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to make the range slider sliding to fill progress element from 0-100
but in the range slider I have different value in the min and the max.

So it cannot be done in a simple on change jquery code...

I cant figure out the way for increment the numbers so it will work smoothly, or maybe my approach is not the one to do it, please advice ?

```js
$(document).on("input change", "#rangeSlider" ,function() {

        var valNumb = parseInt($(this).val());
        
        var newVal = valNumb - 18;
        newVal = newVal++;

        $(".rangeProgress").val(newVal);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="range-slider" type="range" id="rangeSlider" name="range" value="18" min="18" max="99">

<progress class="rangeProgress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do some basic math calculate the percentage based on the `min` and `max` attributes:

```js
$(document).on("input change", "#rangeSlider" ,function() {

        var valNumb = parseInt($(this).val()) - $(this).attr('min');
        var progress = valNumb / ($(this).attr('max') - $(this).attr('min')) * 100

        $(".rangeProgress").val(progress);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="range-slider" type="range" id="rangeSlider" name="range" value="18" min="18" max="99">

<progress class="rangeProgress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: thanks, can you explain how the calculation gose in a few words ? i had some trouble understanding the way i needed to calculate...

Comment: Works, perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).on("input change", "#rangeSlider" ,function() {

        var valNumb = parseInt($(this).val()-this.min);
        var newVal = valNumb/(this.max-this.min)*100;

        $(".rangeProgress").val(newVal);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="range-slider" type="range" id="rangeSlider" name="range" value="18" min="18" max="99">

<progress class="rangeProgress" value="0" max="100"></progress>
```